# Extract Text, Removing Characters After "-"

Tags: sql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I have a column `Plans` like this:

```
   Plans
   OXF-PL10-A
   OXF-PL10-C
   OXF-PL10-P
   OXF-PL10VE
   OXF-PL2-P 
   OXF-PL3-P
```

How can I just grab the text without the characters after the 2nd "-"

I want my data as follows:

```
   Plans
   OXF-PL10
   OXF-PL10
   OXF-PL10
   OXF-PL10VE
   OXF-PL2
   OXF-PL3
```

Note: I'm using regular standard ANSI SQL not MySQL

Comment: `([^\-]+\-[^\-]+).*`

Comment: This would require some string function and those are different in different databases so what database are you actually using?

Comment: Pervasive SQL.  I may just end up using multiple replace functions in this case.

Comment: Maybe something like this is what you want? `select case when locate('-', plans, 6) > 1 then left(plans, locate('-',plans, 6)-1) else plans end from table`

Comment: thank you for letting me know about locate, jpw.  please post this as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposted my comment as requested:

```
select 
  case when locate('-', plans, 6) > 1 then left(plans, locate('-',plans, 6)-1) 
       else plans 
  end 
from table
```